# Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal rest sdk/api and charging to my customers but then i am calling charge section multiple time in loop then at first time my customer's account is debited but other customer's account is not debited when i tried to debug i found this error "Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"

As when loop calls first time the Rest sdk/api charge function then it get success but the it showing error when loop runs further.

Please let me know if you want any other information from my side.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better luck debugging your issue if you wrap any calls which require an `$apiContext` in a try / catch block and examine the exceptions that the SDK throws. I have a function I've been using for this that's been helpful.

```
function PaypalError($e){

    $err = "";

    do {
        if (is_a($e, "PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException")){
            $data = json_decode($e->getData(),true);
            $err .= $data['name'] . " - " . $data['message'] . "<br>";
            if (isset($data['details'])){
                $err .= "<ul>";
                foreach ($data['details'] as $details){
                    $err .= "<li>". $details['field'] . ": " . $details['issue'] . "</li>";
                }
                $err .= "</ul>";
            }
        }else{
            //some other type of error
            $err .= sprintf("%s:%d %s (%d) [%s]\n", $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), get_class($e));
        }
    } while($e = $e->getPrevious());

    return $err;
}
```

Used thusly:

```
try{
    $Payment->create($apiContext); //or any similar calls
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo PaypalError($e);
}
```